# Exact algorithms for $k$-means

Tags: reference-request, optimization, clustering

Lets recall the definition of $k$-means clustering for euclidean spaces.

Let $X$ be a set of $n$ points in $R^d$ and $k$ a given natural number. Let $C$ any $k$ clustering of $X$. Define the cost of $C$

$\phi(C) = \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{x \in C_i} \|x-\mu_i\|_2^2$

where $\mu_i = mean(C_i)$.

Then the goal is to find a $C^*$ minimizing $\phi$. This problem is NP-Hard, even for $k=2$.

However there several approximation algorithms for it, e.g. k-means++; but also constant factor approximation algorithms and PTAS.

What I'm looking for is a reference for exact algorithms (i.e., algorithms finding an optimal clustering) which are not polynomial but better than exhastive search. The only reference I'm aware of is (https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/177424.178042), which is quite old.

Comment: Thanks, I've elaborated more on it.

Comment: @D.W. Technically, k-means is a problem, as defined in the question. It is just that "Lloyd's heuristic" is popularly known as the k-means algorithm.

Comment: I don't know of recent work on absolute worst-case instances, but k-means on smoothed instances can be solved in polynomial time, see [AMR09](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.1113.pdf).

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Are the constant factor approximaion algorithm for this problem?

Comment: @Jut The current best approximation guarantee is $6.129$. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.07358). The first known constant approximation was around 2 decades earlier.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Thank you. Are we have any constant factor approximation algorithm for k-Means in plane?

Comment: @Jut This is not an appropriate place to ask this question. It would be spamming the comment section. You may want to take this discussion to chat; I will answer your questions there.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Unfortunately, I can't take this discussion to chat, because I'm temporarily suspended from Stackexchage.

Comment: @Jut PTAS is known when $d$ is fixed. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08976).